# Directive at angularjs and custom method/html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this code:

```
<body ng-controller="testController">
    <div test-directive transform="transform()">
    </div>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="testDirective.html">
        <div>
            <p>
                {{transform()}}
            </p>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script>
        angular.module("Test", [])
        .directive("testDirective", function() {
            return {
                templateUrl: "testDirective.html",
                scope: {
                    transform: "&"
                },
                link: function(scope) {

                }
            };
        })
        .controller("testController", function($scope) {
            $scope.transform = function() {
                return "<a ng-click='somethingInController()'>Do Something</a>";
            };

            $scope.somethingInController = function() {
                alert("Good!");
            };
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

So basically what I want to accomplish is to create a directive with a method that will be called from the controller. And that method will do something with the values passed (in this example it  does not receives nothing, but in the real code it does).

Up to that point is working. However, the next thing I want to do is create an element that will call a method in the controller. The directive does not knows what kind of element will be (can be anything) nor what method will be. Is there any way to do it?

**Fiddle Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/abrahamsustaita/C57Ft/0/ - Version 0

http://jsfiddle.net/abrahamsustaita/C57Ft/1/ - Version 1

**FIDDLE EXAMPLE WORKING**

http://jsfiddle.net/abrahamsustaita/C57Ft/2/ - Version 2

The version 2 is now working (I'm not sure if this is the way to go, but it works...). However, I cannot execute the method in the parent controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get to get it working.

The solution is combined. First of all, I needed to add another directive to parse the element I wanted:

```
.directive("tableAppendElement", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var el = angular.element("<span />");
            el.append(attrs.element);
            $compile(el)(scope);
            element.append(el);
        }
    }
})
```

This will receive the element/text that will be appended and then will registered it to the scope.

However, the problem still exists. How to access the scope of the controller? Since my directive will be used by a lot of controllers, and will depend on the model of the controller, then I just set scope: false. And with that, every method in the controller is now accessible from the directive :D

See the [fiddle working here](http://jsfiddle.net/abrahamsustaita/C57Ft/3/). This also helped me because now, there is no need to pass the transform method, so the controller can be the one handling that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However there is a few problems with your code. I will start by answering your question.

```
<test-directive transform='mycustommethod'></test-directive>

// transform in the directive scope will point to mycustommethod
angular.module('app').directive('testDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            transform: '&'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that printing the html will be escaped and you will get &lt; instead of < (etc.). You can use ng-bind-html instead but the returned html will not be bound. You will need to inject the html manually (you can use jquery for this) in your link method and use `var compiled = $compile(html)(scope)` to bind the result. Then call `ele.after(compiled)` or `ele.replace(compiled)` to add it to your page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, you misunderstood it. The problem is not with the transform method, it is already there. The problem is the directive does not know the method somethingInController (see http://jsfiddle.net/C57Ft/). Also, I know it will be escaped. Actually that is the problem, how to inject the html in the directive and execute a method at the controller

Comment: Read my full answer. I explain the escaping and why it doesn't know of somethingInController.

Comment: Thanks... I read it, but it does not answer the question. I cannot use the link because the info in the directive's html will be modified by the controller, not by the directive, so I have no `ele` there. Did you see the fiddle?

Comment: I have editd the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/C57Ft/) so you can get a better idea of why what you said will not help me. (Or maybe I'm wrong, and in such case, if you can get me a better idea of how to do it I'll appreciate it)

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue. Now the html is appended, but I cannot call the parent's controller method. Any idea?